# override python module with one that has an extra argument - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I've imported a cool package (if it matters, it's called tweepy).

But there is a small limitation with 2 of the methods due to a recent change Twitter made. There's already a fix but it hasn't been pulled for some time

I was considering trying to temporarily add the fix on my side and override the existing modules until the package is updated, although I'm not quite as experienced with python

```
def statuses_lookup(self, id_, include_entities=None,
                    trim_user=None, map_=None):
    return self._statuses_lookup(list_to_csv(id_), include_entities,
                                 trim_user, map_)

@property
def _statuses_lookup(self):
    """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
        :allowed_param:'id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map'
    """
    return bind_api(
        api=self,
        path='/statuses/lookup.json',
        payload_type='status', payload_list=True,
        allowed_param=['id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map'],
        require_auth=True
    )
```

and overriding that with a similar (difference being adding an extra argument tweet_mode as far as I'm aware):

```
def statuses_lookup(self, id_, include_entities=None,
                    trim_user=None, map_=None, tweet_mode=None):
    return self._statuses_lookup(list_to_csv(id_), include_entities,
                                 trim_user, map_, tweet_mode)

@property
def _statuses_lookup(self):
    """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
        :allowed_param:'id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'
    """
    return bind_api(
        api=self,
        path='/statuses/lookup.json',
        payload_type='status', payload_list=True,
        allowed_param=['id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'],
        require_auth=True
    )
```

I've never really tried something like this before in python 3.X

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @SergeyVasilyev, is it possible to override the existing methods within the import (first code block), with the altered version (second code block)

Comment: since the difference is just another argument. I thought simply adding the alteration into my code should be enough (late binding polymorphism according to my understanding), but then i dont know how that applies to imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the best way to implement is extending from original object and overriding what you want:

```
class CustomAPI(API):
    def statuses_lookup(self, id_, include_entities=None,
                    trim_user=None, map_=None, tweet_mode=None):
        return self._statuses_lookup(list_to_csv(id_), include_entities,
                                 trim_user, map_, tweet_mode)

    @property
    def _statuses_lookup(self):
        """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
            :allowed_param:'id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'
        """
        return bind_api(
            api=self,
            path='/statuses/lookup.json',
            payload_type='status', payload_list=True,
            allowed_param=['id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'],
            require_auth=True
        )
```

Then you can use `CustomAPI` instead of `API`.

## Update

Suppose you create a new `custom_tweepy.py` file:

```
from tweepy import API

class CustomAPI(API):
    def statuses_lookup(self, id_, include_entities=None,
                    trim_user=None, map_=None, tweet_mode=None):
        return self._statuses_lookup(list_to_csv(id_), include_entities,
                                 trim_user, map_, tweet_mode)

    @property
    def _statuses_lookup(self):
        """ :reference: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup
            :allowed_param:'id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'
        """
        return bind_api(
            api=self,
            path='/statuses/lookup.json',
            payload_type='status', payload_list=True,
            allowed_param=['id', 'include_entities', 'trim_user', 'map', 'tweet_mode'],
            require_auth=True
        )
```

Then every other place you originally use `from tweepy import API`, you can replace it with `from custom_tweepy import CustomAPI as API`. Next, you can make your custom API implementation in use. And, you just override these two functions so all other functions are not changed at all.

Comment: if I use customapi instead of api, doesn't that mean i have to modify the import's code to include the class? otherwise tweepy.API wouldn't be replaced by tweepy.CusomAPI

Comment: I also want to retain the functionality of the other methods in API. in effect mimick the behaviour of going into the source code and directly changing the code

Comment: No, you needn't to modify the source code. You can just create a new file which include `from tweepy import API` and your `CustomAPI`. Then you can replace `from tweepy import API` with `from your_file import CustomAPI as API` to use your `CustomAPI`. Also, in this case you just override these two functions, others are not changed at all. I will update my answer to make it more explicit.

Comment: thanks for clarification @sraw. but I have other functions to call from tweepy. i effectively want to use the whole tweepy package but override those two functions. I tried using from tweepy import * in the new customtweepy, and used import customtweepy in my code (while replacing tweepy with customtweepy), although i think it still accesses the old functions because i get an error about TypeError: statuses_lookup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tweet_mode'

Answer (score 1):

Everything is doable.

Here is the simplified solution on how to hack a class. Even if the module was imported, and the class was used to create object — this hack will affect all of the existing objects immediately:

```
class KLS(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        print('OLD')
        return 100

def new_function(self):
    print('NEW')
    return 200

obj = KLS()

print(obj.x)  # OLD + 100    
KLS.x = property(new_function)  # <-- HACK!
print(obj.x)  # NEW + 200
```

The solution works both for py2 & py3.

However, make sure there are no setters/deleters for that property in the original class (i.e., is it settable? or just read-only?) For the setters, you will have to call `property(getter_func, setter_func)`.

Comment: hmm i was thinking of something similar via tweepy.API._statuses_lookup = _statuses_lookup2 and 
tweepy.API.statuses_lookup = statuses_lookup2. I've tried with property(), although I get an error: statuses_lookup2() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id_'

Comment: All I'm really calling is:    api = tweepy.API(auth)
 ((((where above changes were made already))))) and  tweets = api.statuses_lookup(id_batch,tweet_mode='extended')